# Erro em biblioteca libpq-fe.h

Tags: c++, codeblocks, library

Estou utilizando o codeblocks e  a biblioteca  entretanto estou com o seguinte erro:

```
fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or directory
```

Ja adicionei o caminho apontando para o arquivo header pelo seguinte caminho

Project -> Build Options -> linker settings.

Existe alguma outra forma de acessar a esta biblioteca??

Comment: Veja se pode te ajudar. https://github.com/jgallagher/go-libpq/issues/4

Comment: Linux ou Windows ?

Comment: @Lacobus, utilizo Windows.

Comment: @NetinhoSantos, Obrigado pela ajuda, mas tive que instalar outra IDE